# Tesseract baseapi error: 'strncpy':this function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ocr, tesseract

I get the above mentioned error when I use the following in Visual Studio 2012(I am using C++):

```
#include <tesseract\baseapi.h>
```

Could anyone shed some light on what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Non secure CRT functions are deprecated by default. You can enable them back by defining the macro `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. Try -

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <tesseract\baseapi.h>
```

Or add the macro to the project properties list. Read the article [Eliminating Deprecation Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx) at MSDN.

From the article -

> There are several ways to eliminate deprecation warnings for the older, less secure functions. The simplest is simply to define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS or use the warning pragma. Either will disable deprecation warnings, but of course the security issues that caused the warnings still exist. It is far better to leave deprecation warnings enabled and take advantage of the new CRT security features.

Comment: I added that to the beginning of the file. Still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you set the option to treat warnings as errors in VS ? And what is the warning level set ?

Comment: having the same error, I do not treat warnings as errors and I tested it with all warning levels. Any suggestions?

Comment: found out how it works: Properties -> C/C++ --> General --> SDL checks --> No